# Retrieve data based on user id (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im fairly new with php so please bear with me. I have two tables in my database, `users` and `onlineform` tables. The `onlineform`  table have `userid` field as a foreign key for the `id` field in `users` table. Im trying to display data from `onlineform` table based on current user login. The problem is, it display data from all users and not the one who logged in. I have setup a query in my `form_model` but i dont know if the query is correct

this is the model

**form_model.php**:

```
function getEmployees() 
{
    $this->db->select("users.id, onlineform.date, onlineform.day, onlineform.in1, 
        onlineform.out1, onlineform.in2, onlineform.out2");
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('onlineform','users.id = onlineform.userid', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by('date asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

this is the controller

**form.php**

```
public function table()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('username') != '')  
       {     
            $this->load->model('form_model');
            $query = $this->form_model->getEmployees();
            $data['EMPLOYEES'] = null;
            if($query) {
                $data['EMPLOYEES'] =  $query;
            }
       } 

    else  
       {  
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/form/login');  
       }

            $this->load->view('table.php', $data);
}
```

and this is my view

**table.php**

```
<?php 
        foreach($EMPLOYEES as $employee)
          {?>
         <tr>
          <td align="center" 
          <?php if($employee->day === "SAT" || $employee->day === "SUN"): ?> style="background-color:#A9A9A9; color: white;" <?php endif; ?>>
            <strong><?=$employee->day;?></strong>
          </td>
          <td align="center" 
          <?php if($employee->day === "SAT" || $employee->day === "SUN"): ?> style="background-color:#A9A9A9; color: white;" <?php endif; ?>>
            <strong><?=$employee->date;?></strong>
          </td>
          <td><?=$employee->out1;?></td>
          <td><?=$employee->in1;?></td>
          <td><?=$employee->out2;?></td>
          <td><?=$employee->in2;?></td>
         </tr>     
        <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the current logged in userid in session then you can use it when you retrieve the data from database.
change your form_model.php code to this

```
function getEmployees() 
{
    $this->db->select("users.id, onlineform.date, onlineform.day, onlineform.in1, 
        onlineform.out1, onlineform.in2, onlineform.out2");
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('onlineform','users.id = onlineform.userid', 'left');
    $this->db->where("users.id", $this->session->userdata('current_user_id'));
    $this->db->order_by('date asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the current logged in userId into the model through getEmployees($userid)

```
$query = $this->form_model->getEmployees($userid);
```

And then use it in your query to get current userId that matches logged in user, to user in database;

```
function getEmployees($userid) 
{
    $this->db->select("users.id, onlineform.date, onlineform.day, onlineform.in1, 
    onlineform.out1, onlineform.in2, onlineform.out2");
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('onlineform','users.id',$userid); //add this line
    $this->db->join('onlineform','users.id = onlineform.userid', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by('date asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

And then pass it normally to your view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: now its giving me this error, Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: thanks man. it works, just need a few tweaks on the code. thank you very much dude